# Multiple conditions in sql?

Tags: sql

I want to select all rows from my database where the id is equal to either 1,6 or 7.

How can I specify multiple conditions in the query statement?

Comment: Do your research next time. There's plenty of SQL resources online that could have told you this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OR` operations, or for the id choices, an `IN ()` clause is appropriate:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE id IN (1,6,7)
```

If you required conditions on different columns, you would use logical `OR` or `AND`:

```
-- either or...
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE col1 = 'someval' OR col2 = 'someotherval'
-- both conditions met...
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE col1 = 'someval' AND col2 = 'someotherval'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the id to be in a certain set of values, you should use the `in` clause:

```
select * from someTable where id in (1, 6, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your more general question -- you can use keywords `AND` and `OR` to combine multiple predicates.  `AND` means that both predicates must be true, `OR` means that at least one must be true.  If you use both `AND` and `OR` in the same query, it is generally best to use parentheses to be sure that the predicates are associated in the desired order.

Your query could be written as:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE id=1 OR id=6 OR id=7
```

A more complex example might be:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE id=1 OR (id=6 AND col2 = 'X') OR id=7
```